# Is there a way to split the results of a select query into two equal halfs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, result-partitioning

I need a solution for a select query in Sql Server 2005.

I'd like to have a query returning two ResultSets each of which holding exactly half of all records matching a certain criteria. I tried using TOP 50 PERCENT in conjunction with an Order By but if the number of records in the table is odd, one record will show up in both resultsets. I don't want to have any record duplicated over the recordsets. Example:

I've got a simple table with TheID (PK) and TheValue fields (varchar(10)) and 5 records. Skip the where clause for now.

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM TheTable ORDER BY TheID asc
```

results in the selected id's 1,2,3

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM TheTable ORDER BY TheID desc
```

results in the selected id's 3,4,5

3 is a dup. In real life of course the queries are fairly complicated with a ton of where clauses and subqueries.

Comment: Who is consuming these two queries? If both consumers are aware of one another (presumably by their results), why not fetch the whole list and divide it consumer-side so there are no duplicates?

Comment: yes. sorry, i forgot to mention it.

Comment: Could you provide a better example?  Two queries on the same table to return 50% of the table contents is... the entire table.  It's not clear to me either if duplicates are accepted or not.

Comment: Also, how many rows are you talking about in your final output? That could make some solutions better than others.

Comment: can you have 2 unequal halfs?

Comment: I'm sorry for the incomplete question. I'll edit the original posting to clarify a bit more for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 and similar:

```
select *, ntile(2) over(order by theid) as tile_nr from thetable
```

`ntile(n)` allocates the output into n segments, each of the same size (give or take rounding when the number of rows isn't divisible by n). So this produces the output:

```
1 | value1 | 1
2 | value2 | 1
3 | value3 | 1
4 | value4 | 2
5 | value5 | 2
```

If you just want the top or bottom half, you need to put this into a subquery, e.g.:

```
select theid, thevalue from (
  select theid, thevalue, ntile(2) over(order by theid) as tile_nr from thetable
) x
where x.tile_nr = 1
```

will return the top half, and similarly use `x.tile_nr = 2` for the bottom half

Comment: +1, tested it out on my system. @Thomas, there is no `partition by`, just an `order by`

Comment: @KM - Yeah, tested on my system too. This is to me is the cleverest solution assuming SQL2k5+.

Comment: +1 one of the most often overlooked ranking functions, indeed! Great answer

Answer (score 8):

You could use these two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheID) AS rn FROM TheTable
) T1
WHERE rn % 2 = 0

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheID) AS rn FROM TheTable
) T1
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Definitely a viable answer. But doesn't this stripe the distribution of the halves? In the OP, he's getting "the top half" and "the bottom half" as opposed to "two unqualified halves".

Comment: @Mark Canlas: You are correct. My reading of the question was that it doesn't matter which half each record is in, as long as the number of rows is correct. But you have a point that the question could be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 2):

If this is SQL Server 2000, then I'd be inclined to find the PK of the middle value like so:

```
Declare @MiddleId int

Set @MiddleId = (
                Select TOP 1 PK
                From (
                        Select TOP 50 PERCENT PK
                        From Table
                        Order By TheId ASC
                        )
                Order By TheId DESC
                )

Select ...
From Table
Where TheId <= @MiddleId

Select ..
From Table
Where TheId > @MiddleId
```

With SQL Server 2005, I'd be inclined to do the same but you can use a CTE

```
;With NumProjects As
    (
    Select Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheId ASC ) As Num
    From Table
    )
Select @MiddleId = Id
From Table
Where Num = CEILING( (Select Count(*) From Table) / 2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @CountOf int,@Top int,@Bottom int
SELECT @CountOf=COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
SET @Top=@CountOf/2
SET @Bottom=@CountOf-@Top
SELECT TOP (@Top) * FROM YourTable ORDER BY 1 asc --assumes column 1 is your PK
SELECT TOP (@Bottom) * FROM YourTable ORDER BY 1 desc --assumes column 1 is your PK
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

You would need to use a temp table to hold the first 50% as below:

```
select top 50 percent * 
into #YourTempTable
from TheTable 

-- The below would give the first half
select * from #YourTempTable

-- The below woud give rest of the half 
select * from TheTable where TheID not in (select TheID from #YourTempTable)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is [the query](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic707076-1509-1.aspx) I found useful (after modifications of-course):

> > DECLARE @numberofitemsperpage INT DECLARE @numberofpages INT DECLARE @currentpage int
>
> DECLARE @countRecords float SET @countRecords = (Select COUNT(*) From
>   sz_hold_visitsData)
>   -- the Excel can hold approximately ONE MILLION records at a time. if @countRecords >= 1000000 SET @numberofitemsperpage = 500000 ELSE IF
>   @countRecords < 1000000 AND @countRecords >= 500000 SET
>   @numberofitemsperpage  = 250000 ELSE IF @countRecords < 500000 AND
>   @countRecords >= 100000 SET @numberofitemsperpage  = 50000 ELSE SET
>   @numberofitemsperpage  = 10000
>
> DECLARE @numberofpages_deci float SET @numberofpages_deci =
>   @countRecords / @numberofitemsperpage
>
> SET @numberofpages = CEILING(@numberofpages_deci)  Select
>   @countRecords AS  countRecords,  @numberofitemsperpage AS
>   numberofitemsperpage , @numberofpages_deci AS numberofpages_deci,
>   @numberofpages AS numberofpagesFnl
>
> SET @currentpage =0 WHILE @currentpage < @numberofpages  BEGIN SELECT
>   a.* FROM  (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY person_ID) AS ROW, *
>   FROM  sz_hold_visitsData) a WHERE ROW >= @currentpage *
>   @numberofitemsperpage +1 AND Row <= (@currentpage+1) *
>   @numberofitemsperpage
>
> IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK SET @currentpage = @currentpage +1 END

In this extract, "sz_hold_visitsData" is a table in my database, whilst "person_ID" is a column therein.
You can also further modify the script to output to file:

> DECLARE @numberofitemsperpage INT DECLARE @numberofpages INT DECLARE
>   @currentpage int
>
> DECLARE @countRecords float SET @countRecords = (Select COUNT(*) From
>   sz_hold_visitsData)
>   -- the Excel can hold approximately ONE MILLION records at a time. if @countRecords >= 1000000 SET @numberofitemsperpage = 500000 ELSE IF
>   @countRecords < 1000000 AND @countRecords >= 500000 SET
>   @numberofitemsperpage  = 250000 ELSE IF @countRecords < 500000 AND
>   @countRecords >= 100000 SET @numberofitemsperpage  = 50000 ELSE SET
>   @numberofitemsperpage  = 10000
>
> DECLARE @numberofpages_deci float SET @numberofpages_deci =
>   @countRecords / @numberofitemsperpage
>
> SET @numberofpages = CEILING(@numberofpages_deci)  Select
>   @countRecords AS  countRecords,  @numberofitemsperpage AS
>   numberofitemsperpage , @numberofpages_deci AS numberofpages_deci,
>   @numberofpages AS numberofpagesFnl
>
> DECLARE @sevrName nvarchar(50) SET @sevrName = '.\sql14' DECLARE
>   @outputFile nvarchar(500)
>
> SET @currentpage =0 WHILE @currentpage < @numberofpages  BEGIN
>   --SELECT a.*  FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY person_ID) AS ROW, * FROM sz_hold_visitsData) a WHERE ROW >= @currentpage *
>   @numberofitemsperpage +1 AND Row <= (@currentpage+1) *
>   @numberofitemsperpage SET @outputFile = 'C:\PSM\outVisits_'
>   +convert(nvarchar(50), @currentpage) + '.csv'     --Select @outputFile --TEST
>
> DECLARE @cmd_ varchar(500) = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @sevrName + ' -E -Q
>   "SELECT a.*  FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY person_ID) AS
>   ROW, * FROM sz_hold_visitsData) a WHERE ROW >= '+
>   CONVERT(nvarchar(500),@currentpage * @numberofitemsperpage +1) +' AND
>   Row <= ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(500),((@currentpage+1) *
>   @numberofitemsperpage)) +'"  -s "," -o ' +@outputFile +' ' -- 
>   "C:\PSM\outVisits.csv" ' EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd_
>
> IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK SET @currentpage = @currentpage +1 END

Hope helps.

Comment: Please markup your code the prescribed way - leave a blank line and indent each line of code with 4 spaces.