# Split the results of a query in half

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to export rows from one database to Excel and I'm limited to 65000 rows at a shot.  That tells me I'm working with an Access database but I'm not sure since this is a 3rd party application (MRI Netsource) with limited query ability.  I've tried the options posted at this solution ([Is there a way to split the results of a select query into two equal halfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776006/is-there-a-way-to-split-the-results-of-a-select-query-into-two-equal-halfs)) but neither of them work -- in fact, they end up duplicating results rather than cutting them in half.

One possibly related issue is that this table does not have a unique ID field.  Each record's unique ID can be dynamically formed by the concatenation of several text fields.

This produces 91934 results:

```
SELECT * from note
```

This produces 122731 results:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY notedate) AS rn FROM note
) T1
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
```

EDIT: Likewise, this produces 91934 results, half of them with a tile_nr value of 1, the other half with a value of 2:

```
SELECT *, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY notedate) AS tile_nr FROM note
```

However this produces 122778 results, all of which have a tile_nr value of 1:

```
SELECT bldgid, leasid, notedate, ref1, ref2, tile_nr
FROM (
     SELECT *, NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY notedate) AS tile_nr FROM note) x
WHERE x.tile_nr = 1
```

I know that I could just use a COUNT to get the exact number of records, run one query using TOP 65000 ORDER BY notedate, and then another that says TOP 26934 ORDER BY notedate DESC, for example, but as this dataset changes a lot I'd prefer some way to automate this to save time.

Comment: You are running queries against an application called MRI NetSource? Because Access doesn't support window functions.

Comment: Does your data source allow export to anything other than Excel?  Or does it offer ODBC connections?

Comment: @Yawar: MRI Netsource is the container application for the database which I'm only assuming is Access because of the 65000 row export limit.  It may not be Access.

Comment: @HansUp: No, unfortunately not -- that would be wonderful if it did but they're very restrictive.

Comment: Access doesn't have a 65000 record limit as far as I know. That sounds  more like an old Excel (xls) limitation. Also, access doesn't support the Row_Number() function. I suspect you are not hitting an Access database.

Comment: You may be right and this may not be Access at all -- I just Googled "export 65000 records to Excel" and got a bunch of hits saying you can't do that in Access.

Comment: there must be a way to inspect the connection string through your application...

Comment: Unfortunately not, here's what I have to work with: http://tentenstudios.com/storage/mri_sql_query.png

Comment: Excel 2003 has the 65,xxx row limit, but Excel 2010 has 1,048,576 rows limit. Have you tried to export the entire file?  Is it 2010 format?

Comment: No, it's exporting into the older format and I have no control over that as I'm accessing the application through a Citrix session.