# SQL Server: Is there a way to split SELECT query results into two vertical halves?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776006/is-there-a-way-to-split-the-results-of-a-select-query-into-two-equal-halfs) deals with **horizontal** splitting, where the upper half of the rows and the lower half of the rows are separated.

My question is focused on **vertical** splitting:

Given that 200 columns are named A001, A002, ..., A199, A200, another 200 columns are named B501, B502, ..., B699, B700, and the primary key is a column named ID:

Is it possible to save ID and the columns starting with A into one temporary table and ID and the columns starting with B into another temporary table?

NOTE: Data is NOT sourced from an existing table, but from a series of nested `SELECT ... AS` Inner Query statements.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT

ID
,A001
,A002
/...other statements here .../

INTO #TEMP_Table1

FROM (
SELECT

ID
,A001
,A002
/...other statements here .../
,A001+A002+A003+A004+A005+A006+A007+A008+A009 A010
,A011+A012+A013+A014+A015+A016+A017+A018+A019 A020
/...other statements here .../
,CASE WHEN C501>0 THEN B501/C501 ELSE 0 B501
,CASE WHEN C502>0 THEN B502/C502 ELSE 0 B502
/...other statements here .../

FROM (
SELECT 

ID
,CASE WHEN A0=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END A001
,CASE WHEN A0=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END A002
/...other statements here .../
,SUM(B1) OVER (ORDER BY C5,D0) B501
,SUM(B2) OVER (ORDER BY C5,D0) B502
/...other statements here .../
,E501+F501 C501
,E502+F502 C502
/...other statements here .../

FROM
[dbo].[TheTableHist]

WHERE SubID = 'X158'

) AS xx1
) AS xx2
```

So, it will work for the first temporary table only. But how about the second, when I can no longer `SELECT` the columns starting with B, as they have been excluded when selecting the columns for the first temporary table?

ADDITIONAL EDIT: You may suggest that I save the entire results into a temporary table, then refer to that temporary table and extract those columns starting with A, and then extract those starting with B.

However, I can't save the entire results in a temporary table, as I have gone beyond the 8060 bytes per row.

Which is why I need to save it in two parts.

Comment: Kinda hard. I'd think the faster way would be to 1) unpivot (I propose using cross apply instead of the more complicated UNPIVOT operator) 2) now do what you call "horizontal splitting" 3) if you want, pivot back. The alternative is dynamic sql.

Comment: ok, i'll add an example.

Comment: Sounds like the design has taken a wrong somewhere along the way. 200 columns in a table is way beyond what is expected in a well designed and normalized table. And now you are struggling with it because the amount of data per row exceeds the max. Seems like revisiting the architecture might be a your best course of action.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, that what I actually did now, but I was thinking there was some way around it, aside from revising the architecture

Comment: You could use two queries. One to get the "first half" of the columns and another query for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT ID, A001, ... , A200 INTO Tempa FROM Table ;
SELECT ID, B501, ... , B700 INTO Tempb FROM Table ;
```

EDIT:

Just for the fun of it, I assume it would be very slow, but maybe this could work(can't test it, having no SQL server):

You could create a view with all the columns and write an [instead of insert trigger](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/), which separates each row into A and B columns and inserts them into distinct temp tables.

Then you fire

```
SELECT * from <your select> into view_name
```

Comment: No. Data is not sourced form an existing Table, but a couple of nested SELECT SubQueries

Comment: @qzx then put first you Data into a temporary table o variable table, and then you can split it as Turo says.

Comment: I can't, as I've gone beyond the 8060 bytes limit per row. That's why I need to split it vertically into 2.